# firebase authentication ios use of unresolved identifier 'handle'

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start) for Firebase authentication.. I kinda just followed the code but keep having the **Use of unresolved identifier 'handle'** error.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class SignInViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in   // ERROR HERE
            // ...
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle!)    // ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

Any clue what I should do? Thanks!

```
    @IBAction func createAccount(_ sender: Any) {


        let emailTextD = self.emailText.text!
        let passwordTextD = self.passwordText.text

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextD, password: passwordTextD!) { (authResult, error) in
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the variable declaration into the class like this:

```
  var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
```

Comment: thanks the error disappeared. but somehow a new user is still not added to the Authentication platform. any idea why? Thanks!